# Disabling inupt field in angular 6 in front end

Tags: angular

In angular i have one input text field which accepts only numbers if suppose there are six numbers entered in feild and deleted using right click from mouse and select cut then after data is gone text box must disable what is solution ?

Comment: You can create the custom directive and use

Comment: Not clear to me! Can you explain or post some code

Comment: There is a text box with add button now if I add 6 digits select the digits with mouse right click -- cut --- and then when the text box is empty the add button should be disabled in angular 6

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactive forms in Angular 6, this can be easily done. Where your component.ts file should render the form. And the add button in html file will only be enabled if the form is valid.(`[disabled]="!form.valid"`)

You can check  [this example](https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/) for use of reactive forms, validators etc in Angular 6.
I Hope, this will help.